# Implementing multiple interfaces in a class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have two interface, interface i1 and interface i2. Both of them have different methods.
class c1 is extending interface i1 and interface i2.
I am using dependency injection and want to inject the c1 dependency. 
Also as a good programming practice we should also code to interface. But if i declare a reference variable using i1 then i cant use i2 methods and vice versa.

Also i want that i1 and i2 to be separate interfaces because i1 is being implemented by other classes as well and those classes don't need i2 methods.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

For example:

```
public interface Tree {
    public int findMin();
    public int findMax();
}
```

```
public interface IBalancedTree {
    public int rightRotation();
}
```

```
class NormalTree extends Tree {
    public int findMin(){
        // implementing find min
    }
    public int findMax(){
        // implementing find max
    }
}
```

```
class BalancedTree extends Tree, IBalancedTree {

    public int findMin(){
        // implementing find min
    }

    public int findMax(){
        // implementing find max
    }

    public int rightRotation(){
        // implementing right rotation
    }
}
```

```
class TreeManager {
    private Tree tree

    public TreeManager(Tree tree){
        this.tree=tree
    }

    //calling tree methods
    //even if i pass balanced tree object i can only call methods of tree class?.
}
```

Comment: please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is no problem. Classes can implement `i1` without implementing `i2` even if `i2` extends `i1`. And where you need to access `i2` methods declare the methods parameter of type `i2` instead of `i1`.

Comment: You can create another interface that will extend both interfaces:public interface i3 extends i1, i2'

Comment: @Krzysztof : I don't think that will work.  I wont be able to declare the 3rd interface as a constructor argument in TreeManager class. As my NormalTree and BalancedTree is not extending the 3rd interface

Answer (score 0):

You can make `IBalancedTree` extend `Tree`.

```
public interface IBalancedTree extends Tree {
    public int rightRotation();
}
```

Then a `Tree` variable can use `Tree` methods and a `IBalancedTree` variable can use both methods. But I think you can  also use `instanceof`.